# String concatenation does not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
foreach (string di_child in dirs) { 
Response.Write("\t<li class=\"directory collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" + drive + di_child.Name + "/\">" + di_child.Name + "</a>\n");
}
```

VS complains that operators '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and method group.

I just want to concatenate those strings. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is drive, sounds like it is a method perhaps you need to use drive()?

Comment: Impossible to tell what's going on here because we don't know any of the types involved... `drive`, `dirs`, `di_child.Name`.

Comment: `drive` or `di_child.Name` is method. Use `drive()` or `di_child.Name()` (according to the type).

Comment: Also Name isn't a valid property of string!

Comment: @Guilherme: Suggest you post more of your code so that this question doesn't get closed. At the moment there are mistakes in your question that suggest you're asking us to tackle a problem that is different to what you say you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Question:

you are iterating string values and concatenating string.Name. I don't think there is any property 'Name' attached to a string.

Comment: That was my problem. Thanks

Comment: Lol. How did you not looked at intellisense that doesn't have any Name property of the string type. :)

Comment: Welcome! For few minutes, I also got confused when i saw so many people answering different things. --codespread.com

Comment: @AzharKhorasany From the error message, there must be an extension method called Name and so intellisense probably wouldn't have spotted it.

Comment: Sharp eye @CodeSpread. Looks like no one saw the real issue here. We're just like compilers, we go crazy on the wrong point and don't step back...

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I am maintaining my site codespread.com where i attempt to look for simple concepts.I believe we are running behind complexity and making it more complex so now is the time to relax and look for simple points

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `StringBuilder.Append()`, something like this:-

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append(someString);
```

or try this:

```
  "\t<li class=\"directory collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" + drive() + di_child.Name + "/\">" + di_child.Name + "</a>\n"
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the `StringBuilder` here though it's better than the + operator. In a simple case like this, I'd prefer the `String.Format()` method to achieve the goal.

Comment: @Nick.T:- Thats correct. I have just recommended one approach as I thought OP might use if working with large strings!! else String.format is definitely one other approach!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `drive` is actually a function, in which case you should call it like this:

```
 "\t<li class=\"directory collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" + drive() + di_child.Name + "/\">" + di_child.Name + "</a>\n"
```

Comment: how come you get to know drive is function not variable..

Comment: Probably because he read the error in the question, and didn't just write a standard string concat answer like the 6 other people

Comment: drive is a DriveInfo local variable. It was concatenating to di_child when my foreach function was foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo di_child in dirs)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach (string di_child in dirs) { 
  Response.Write(String.Format("\t<li class=\"directory collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"{0}{1}/\">{2}</a>\n",drive,di_child.Name,di_child.Name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message occurs because either `drive` or `di_child.Name` is a method and not a string.

In your foreach loop you are declaring `di_child` to be a `string` and `Name` is not a valid property of `string`.

Can you confirm the type of drive?  If it is a function you may need to use it as `drive()`.

The problem may actually because the compiler is using an Extension Method for name and you simply need to use `di_child` instead of `di_child.Name`

Answer (score 0):

You say in one of your comments that drive is a DriveInfo local variable

Giving that di_chld is a string variable, and given that the DriveInfo class has a Name property, I'm guessing that you are calling .Name on the wrong thing so I'm guessing you are supposed to have this:

```
Response.Write("\t<li class=\"directory collapsed\"><a href=\"#\" rel=\"" + drive.Name + di_child + "/\">" + di_child + "</a>\n");
```

As some people have suggested, it's usually better to use String.Format or a StringBuilder for string concatenation